# Add my own command to the PATH

Tags: command-line

I got an executable file(`edit_envir`) in `/home/pshizh/Desktop/` directory. I updated `/etc/environment` file to make `/home/pshizh/Desktop` included in `PATH`. Then I ran command `edit_envir` in terminal, but it said `"dit_envir command not found`. However, after I copied file `edit_envir` to `/usr/bin/` and ran command `edit_envir` in terminal again, it worked. Why? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you edit `/etc/environment` file, if you want the change to take effect, you need to log out and log back in or to source that file in terminal as follow:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Anyway, **this is not an indicated method** to add a directory to the PATH. See the following post in this sense:

- [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: The confusion may be that `/etc/environment` is recommended here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables Other methods are also advised against at that link.

Comment: The question you link is nice, but some information is outdated. Actually it's a messy post with good and bad things, and I guess it's better for the OP if we answer specifically his question here. Cheers `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf If you feel this, then add your new answer there. There is no problem to answer to old questions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't edit the `/etc/environment` file!!! revert the changes and put it back as it originally were. Your system is supposed to work with multiple users. Imagine you create another user, say `johndoe`. Then what will happen when he logs in? he'll have, in his `PATH` variable your directory `/home/pshizd/Desktop`. I'm sure he doesn't care about that!

Instead, modify the `PATH` variable from within your own personal `.bashrc` file: add this snippet at the end of your `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=/home/pshizd/Desktop:$PATH
```

Now wait, your own scripts are not supposed to be located on your Desktop. Instead, create a `bin` directory in your home directory, put your scripts there, and instead of the previous command in your `.bashrc` file, put this:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you modify the file `.bashrc`, the changes will only take effect in new terminals.

---

Now, if you want this script to be available to all users (e.g., you'll want `johndoe` to be able to execute it, yet he should not have access to your personal directory), the best place is to put the script in `/usr/local/bin`. This directory should already exist (create it if necessary), and should already be in every user's `PATH`. Check that by inspecting the `/etc/profile` file (but do not modify this file!); you could also `grep` `PATH` in there, as so (with some contextual lines):

```
grep -C4 PATH /etc/profile
```

you should see that `/usr/local/bin` is added to the user's `PATH`.

By the way, do not put your own commands in `/usr/bin`! This place is for your distribution's binaries, not your personal ones.

---

Regarding why it didn't work after modifying `/etc/environment`: you need to open a new terminal for changes to take effect.

Comment: Now I've got you :). This doesn't answer to the question. Why after editing `/etc/environment`, the PATH doesn't change?

Comment: And: *Don't edit the /etc/environment file!!!!!!* sound to much scary - give some explanations if you want to say what are the risks.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu You're right, I don't exactly answer the question, instead I give what the OP should do to make things work. Regarding the scary advice, I'll edit my post `;)`.